# sonatype nexus does not fully log in

Tags: authentication, upgrade, nexus

I just upgraded from nexus 1.8.0.1 to 2.8.0-05 and now I cannot fully log in anymore. When I try to login nothing happens. There is still the "Log In" button on the top right and the menu on the left does not show anything (except what was there when not being logged in). So, the login has no effect.

I also tried to log in with invalid account info and it gives me the login error ("incorrect username, pass..."), so the login data is checked. I tried it with the admin and with a user login - no difference. The actual content is still there (all repos with artifacts) and are shown in a browser.

How can I log in?

Details:
I upgraded from nexus 1.8.0.1 to 2.7.2-03 (file: "nexus-2.7.2-bundle.tar") and then to 2.8.0-05 (file: "nexus-2.8.0-05-bundle.tar") on my CentOS 5.10 according to the [upgrade notes](https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Upgrading+Nexus) and some [instructions](http://wiki.ivonet.nl/display/LINUX/Install+or+Upgrade+Sonatype+Nexus)  I found (except for the step with plexus as there was no such file). For nexus 2.7 I got an InvalidMagicMimeEntryException but according to NEXUS-6102 this was fixed in 2.8 and therefore I went on with upgrading to 2.8 and it does not happen anymore - I'm not sure, if this has caused the problem.

Comment: Solution: There was a ProxyPassReverseCookiePath setting in the http.conf. After removing it the login worked again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark... but I do know of an issue that could cause this.  If you have an SSL enabled reverse proxy (like nginx or Apache+mod_proxy) in front of Nexus you need to make sure it is setting the X-Forwarded-Proto header.  If you're using apache you can do this with:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

If this isn't the problem I'm going to need some diagnostic information.  If you can submit your nexus.log file to https://support.sonatype.com I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The problem was a ProxyPassReverseCookiePath. Thanks to your suggestion I knew where to look and was able to find the problem.